# V-html directive not working with fetched data

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, vue.js

Maybe someone can help me solving the problem with `v-html` directive

I have a column in database table with pure html code. I'm getting it through PHP script via fetch.

Here's the code of fetch request (just a usual fetch code):

```
const vacancies: Array<Vacancy> = await fetch(SCRIPT_URL)
    .then((data: Response) => data.json())
    .then((data: Array<Vacancy>) => {
        this.vacancies = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
```

This code is executed on mounting the application. Then i'm trying to render it with following code:

```
<p class="vacancy__info-text" v-for="vacancy in vacancies" v-html="vacancy"></p>
```

But when I'm reloading the page, v-html doesn't render this like html - it renders it like unescaped html:

```
<div> Lorem ipsum <ul> <li>dolor sit amet</li> <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li> <li>eiusmod tempor</li> </ul> </div>
```

Comment: Can you also please post the `vacancies` Array data?

Comment: it has just an array of strings

Comment: Your code looks correct, can you post the data so that we can try replicating the issue. We need to know what kind of strings (or HTML) that is in the `vacancies` Array